# Producing a report with a stored SQL function

Tags: sql, stored-functions, oracle12c

I am trying to produce a report that calculates a discount applied to an order using a stored function in Oracle 12c. I have a table, orders with column o_id. Each line of the order is a separate order_line table, having o_id, ol_quantity, and ol_price. If the order is over $100, a discount of $10 is applied to the order.

I have created a stored function, which compiles, but when I try to run the function I get the error:

```
Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FINAL_COST" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + / at mod remainder rem then <an exponent (**)> and or    || multiset
```

Here is the function:

```
create or replace function DiscountsReport
(order_id IN REAL) RETURN REAL 
is
percent real;
final_cost real;
being
select SUM(order_line.ol_quantity * order_line.ol_price) as total from order_line
where o_id = order_id;
if total >= 100 final_cost = 90;
return final_cost;
end;
```

And my code to run it is:

```
var cost number;
execute :cost := discountsreport(1);
print cost;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "if" statement is absolutely incorrect. Take a look at the documentation:
[if-then-else](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)

Comment: Okay yeah. Thanks. I changed it to:

create or replace function DiscountsReport

(order_id IN REAL) RETURN REAL 

is

percent real;

total real;

final_cost real;

begin

select SUM(order_line.ol_quantity * order_line.ol_price) from 
order_line o into total where o.o_id = order_id;

if 

total >= 100 

then

final_cost := 90; 

end if;

return final_cost;

end;

/ but I'm still getting errors.